Webhook error Google chat with Hubspot workflow integration
I just created a workflow from the HubSpot CRM using the webhook tool, entering the webhook url that provides me with a public space (chat) on Google Chat.
But this gives me the following error (image attached).
I copied this procedure from another company that does work, so I don't understand where the error is. I appreciate your help.
I asked CRM support and they told me that the problem comes from Google Chat, this what they answered me:
"I understand that you are facing errors in this workflow.
If we look at the details here, it shows us:
'The server responded with a client error'
Server response
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Texto\" at 'message': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "message",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Texto\" at 'message': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

I see that both errors are the same.
I recommend working with your developer to resolve this, Fernando. And I see that you can request assistance with this API here in the Google developer documentation.
I hope this helps. If you have any other questions related to this topic, please do not hesitate to contact me again, I will be happy to help you."
